# PreferenceActivity and BroadcastReceiver - Implement dynamic preferences

Tags: java, android

I'm going by the following code example to dynamically build a preference activity.

http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/PreferencesFromCode.html

The preference dialog shows, but I'm not able to see any changes after closing it.

Here's where I'm defining the activity in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity 
          android:name="PreferencesActivity" android:label="@string/preferences_name">
    </activity>
```

Here's where I'm defining the receiver.

```
    <receiver
            android:name="FroyVisualReceiver"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.starlon.froyvisuals.PREFS_UPDATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And here's the BroadcastReceiver. I never see the "WTF" in logcat. What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.starlon.froyvisuals;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class FroyVisualsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.e("WTFWTF", "WTFWTFWTFW");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals("com.starlon.froyvisuals.PREFS_UPDATE"))
        {
            ((FroyVisuals)context).updatePrefs();
        }
    }
}
```

Oh here's onPause where I'm broadcasting the PREFS_UPDATE intent.I do see the logcat message. This method is part of my PreferenceActivity.

```
    /** another activity comes over this activity */
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause ================================ ");
        super.onPause();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, FroyVisualsReceiver.class);
        i.setAction("com.starlon.froyvisuals.PREFS_UPDATE");
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }
```

Edit: I think it may have to do with this line. 'this' points to my PreferenceActivity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, FroyVisualsReceiver.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a simple `Intent`:

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
 i.setAction("com.starlon.froyvisuals.PREFS_UPDATE");
 sendBroadcast(i);
```

Comment: I think that worked, but the line `((FroyVisuals)context).updatePrefs()` crashes it, with a  `E/AndroidRuntime( 8545): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.starlon.froyvisuals.FroyVisualsReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext
`

Comment: Although that's a little unrelated to the original issue I guess. :)

Comment: @Scott The context you are trying to use as a `FroyVisuals` isn't what exactly are you expecting. With an activity registered `BroadcastReceiver` the context in the method `onReceive` is the context of that activity but for a broadcastreceiver set in the manifest I don't know what context do you get(maybe application context?). And i don't understand what are you trying to update in the `FroyVisuals`.

Comment: I discovered that the Context in onReceive() isn't what I thought it was, as you've stated yourself. I'm not sure how to get my FroyVisuals instance from inside the BroadcastReceiver instance.

Comment: Oh and `updatePrefs()` is a custom method I've created. It just updates the Activity's internal fields to match the preferences set by user in PrefferenceActivity instance.

Comment: @Scott I don't know if that will work. One alternative way will be a simple `boolean` set in the preferences of the PreferencesActivity(in the `onPause` method instead of the senBroadcast) and check if that flag has been set (if we've been to the preferences) in the `onResume` method of the `FroyVisuals` activity. If the flag is true then call the method `updatePrefs` if not the preferences haven't been visited so there is no need to call the method(don't forget to set the flag to `false` after you've called the method `updatePrefs`).

Comment: I just placed the BroadcastReceiver inside the FroyVisuals class so now I have access to the method. Thanks for all the help and suggestions. :)